# In Android Studio Hedgehog I can't find flutter attach

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I updated Android Studio to the latest version, but I can't find the entrance to `flutter attach`. I use the command line `flutter attach` and it works. but if I use it this way, I completely lose the `hot reload` function provided by the IDE immediately after saving.

[image]

By the way, I am using the `flutter module`, which is mixed with the iOS project. so I cannot start the `flutter module` directly. I tried to create a new `flutter application`. After running it using `Android Studio Hedgehog`, I can indeed see the `hot reload` button in the log output, but this is not what I want. What I want is the `flutter attach` button in the upper right corner of the old version of `Android Studio`

**Update:**
I found what I wanted on `Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 3`, but I still don’t know how to configure it to display it on `Android Studio Hedgehog`.

[image]

Comment: That attach debugger icon is only visible if you're doing an Android project but if you're doing a Flutter project then there is no way to attach a debugger when project is running. You will need to stop the project and run it again with the debugging mode.

Comment: I can't remember which version of Android Studio I was used, but when I open the Flutter project, there is indeed a `flutter attach` icon.

Comment: @KaranMehta I think there's a difference between "flutter attach" and "attach debugger". The "attach debugger" button actually shows in OP's screenshot. In my Android Studio the "flutter attach" is right next to "attach debugger". I'm also running Android Studio Hedgehog but on Windows. But personally I don't even know when you actually need to use "flutter attach"

Comment: I found what I wanted on `Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 3`, but I still don’t know how to configure it to display it on `Android Studio Hedgehog`. I've updated the question.

Comment: as Ivo said, why at all do you need that "flutter attach'? I heard numerous reports that "flutter attach" sometimes runs but more often people had serious problems with it

Comment: @pskink Because I want to refresh the UI immediately after editing the dart file.

Comment: so use "hot reload", what does "flutter attach" have to do with it?

Comment: @pskink Because I am using the `flutter module`, a hybrid iOS development project, not a `flutter application`, and cannot run dart directly. I need to run it on iOS first, enter the flutter page, and then `flutter attach` before I can use `hot reload`.

Comment: try `ctrl-shift-a` and type `attach` - you should see "flutter attach" action then